# Numbering author posts in posts query

Tags: posts, query, author

What i want to get and have no clue how start is:

Query posts (for example from specific category, ordered by date) but to have the posts from same author numbered by there count in that posts list.

> **For example:**
>
> **Date:** 1/8/2017 **Title:** Great post **Author:** John **Number:** 1
>
> **Date:** 1/7/2017 **Title:** Thrilling post **Author:** Mike **Number:** 1
>
> **Date:** 1/6/2017 **Title:** New post **Author:** John **Number:** 2
>
> **Date:** 1/5/2017 **Title:** Exiting post **Author:** Nathan **Number:** 1
>
> **Date:** 1/4/2017 **Title:** Best post **Author:** Gandi **Number:** 1
>
> **Date:** 1/3/2017 **Title:** Boring post **Author:** John **Number:** 3
>
> **Date:** 1/2/2017 **Title:** Amazing post **Author:** Gandi **Number:** 2
>
> **Date:** 1/1/2017 **Title:** Another post **Author:** Michael **Number:** 1

Of course i'm looking for an elegant, shortest code possible, simple way.

**Edit:** I thought of an idea:
Maybe i can somehow use the author id as a new variable name, adding to this variable each post loop (while) and echoing it.

So i tried:

```
++${the_author_meta( ID )}; echo ${the_author_meta( ID )};
```

which i thought would create a variable named by the author id (for example: `$465`) and would add to it 1 (so `$465 = 1`) and echo '1'. but it doesn't :) actually `++${the_author_meta( ID )};` it self echoes the author id twice...

Answer (score 0):

You could have an authors totals array and on each iteration you would increment that author's key:

```
<?php foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <?php $author_count = isset( $authors_totals[ get_the_author_meta('ID') ] ) ? int_val( $authors_totals[ get_the_author_meta('ID') ] ) + 1 : 1; ?>
    Date: <?php the_date('d/m/Y'); ?> 
    Title: <?php the_title(); ?> 
    Author: <?php the_author(); ?>: <?php echo $author_count; ?>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can just keep a counter of which authors already were in the list like so

```
// Counting
$authors_printed = array();
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        $author = get_the_author();
        if (empty($authors_printed[ $author ])) {
            $authors_printed[ $author ] = 1;
        } else {
            $authors_printed[ $author ]++;
        }
        // now $authors_printed[ $author ] has the correct number
        // more code..
    }
}
```